# Code not executing inside dynamically created <script> element with type "text/jsx"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am working on an application where I need to load scripts dynamically. I tried to load scripts using createElement method. As it is an React application I need to set type attribute of script tag as "text/jsx". I did something like this:

```
  var headTag = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  var scriptEle = document.createElement("script");
  scriptEle.src = "app.js";
  scriptEle.setAttribute("type","text/jsx");
  headTag.appendChild(scriptEle);
  scriptEle.onload = function() {
    //success
  }
  scriptEle.onerror = function(error) {
    //error
  }
```

If I set attribute type to "text/jsx", code inside file app.js is not executing. Also onload and onerror is not executing.

Is there any way execute app.js code, keeping type to "text/jsx" ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you using `require` at build time for this?

Answer (score 0):

Browser can't understand/compile `jsx` that is why we have javascript transpiler; which will compile your code into native javascript and then you can include it here.

Chcek [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-jsx/) here